# line break disappeared when change text style

Tags: plugins, styles, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR 3.X. I have made a plugin to change font style (don't want to use 'stylesheetparser' as I want to change style by one-click only)

In plugin.js:

```
exec : function( editor )
{ 
           var style = new CKEDITOR.style(
                 { styles: { 'color': 'Purple'}}); 
           style.apply(editor.document); 
     }
```

It works, but if I select sentence that include the last char of the line,  it remove the line-break in text , then join 2 lines together....

```
**testing line1**

testing line2
```

become

```
**testing line1**testing line2
```

Any suggestion to fix this?Thx~~